# Does dnsmasq honor no-resolv when resolv-file is specified?

Tags: dnsmasq

Do these dnsmasq options conflict? The router wants to write `resolv-file` to the config, but allows me to append `no-resolv`. Will `dnsmasq` agree to ignore `resolv-file` in this case?

```
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.dnsmasq
no-resolv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will dnsmasq agree to ignore resolv-file in this case?

Checking `dnsmasq` 2.76 [source](https://github.com/imp/dnsmasq/blob/v2.76/src/dnsmasq.c#L778),

```c
if (daemon->port != 0 && option_bool(OPT_NO_RESOLV))
    {
      if (daemon->resolv_files && !daemon->resolv_files->is_default)
    my_syslog(LOG_WARNING, _("warning: ignoring resolv-file flag because no-resolv is set"));
      daemon->resolv_files = NULL;
```

`dnsmasq` will check if `OPT_NO_RESOLV` (`no-resolv` option) is enabled. If so, and `resolv_file` is set and not its default value, it'll set `resolv_file` to `NULL` and emit a warning.

So, yeah, `dnsmasq` will ignore `resolv-file` if `no-resolv` is set.